# android ContentProvider query condition issue

Tags: android, sqlite

Get sucked with Sqlite query, here is my question, take MediaStore.Audio.Artist.Artist as example,

```
String[] projection={MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST};
String selectionClause=MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ?";
String[] selectionArgs={"Artist1","Artist2"};
```

only want to get back results which match String "Artist1" and "Artist2",but I  get error like below,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.
```

Please tell me what wrong with that and correct way to do, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Emanue and CL,base on their ideas, below is solution,

```
MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ? OR " + MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ?";
```

As you can see, here you should use "OR" rather than "AND", if wanting queried results would match selectionArgs. 
PS. numbers of selectionArgs items should be same with numbers of selectionClause.

Again thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have as many '?' in the clause parameters as you will have in the arguments.
In this case it would be something like:

```
MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ? AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ?";
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but unfortunately follow you answer, cursoradapter will not be called, no idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not being called". Make sure your query will return valid results and then debug it step-by-step

Comment: sorry for my expression is not so clear, what I mean is when using ur idea, the method bindView of CursorAdapter will not be executed. I set Log.e command in bindView, and find Log.e not be run

Comment: - Make sure you do get results from the query - make sure you override the "getCount()" in your adapter with the results array size

Comment: The "and" in the question actually means "OR".

Comment: sure, I have overrided getCount() method which return cursor.getCount; but still if bingView not being executed.

Comment: YES, "and" means "or" in my question, sorry for not let it be clear. You mean I should change Emanuel answer into like that, "MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ? OR" + MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST+" = ?"